# Using JavaScript to detect CPU used from within your browser

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the cpu using javascript from within my browser. There is some way to get ones gpu which I found here: https://gist.github.com/cvan/042b2448fcecefafbb6a91469484cdf8

Now I want to get similiar results for cpu detection.

For the Gpu detection I get a clear result like this:
    ATI Technologies Inc. AMD Radeon R9 M370X OpenGL Engine
However for my cpu detection I only get
x86 or Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64

```
//for internet explorer I tried this code:
function function1() {
var m = navigator.cpuClass;
console.log(m);}
//for mozilla firefox I tried this code:
function function1() {
var m = navigator.oscpu;
console.log(m);}
```

However the output I have is not satisfying.

Comment: That's pretty much all you can get with pure JS, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817775/can-i-detect-cpu-type-and-speed-and-or-amount-of-ram-a-computer-has-from-a-web

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!why can you detect the gpu through JS though but not the cpu?

Comment: Who knows, probably it's a part of the security features, and also, CPU information isn't actually useful in JS programms, there's no decisions to make based on the type of the CPU.