# wasm binary giving wrong output as compared to running binary in terminal

Tags: node.js, go, server, cpu, webassembly

I have a go program (https://github.com/klauspost/cpuid) which I'm running in my terminal and it works perfectly fine.
I wanted to make it like a service running in browser. The only way possible I see is to compile it to wasm binary and serve the file statically.

But the problem is, output in terminal and browser are different. Anything I'm missing here?

1. go code is available in repo shared above
2. programm is compiled to wasm using `GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o test.wasm test.go`
3. Js code to serve statically

```js
const http = require('http');

const nStatic = require('node-static');

// wasm file is in public folder. 
// wasm_exec.js is used which is available in go installtion
const fileServer = new nStatic.Server('./public');

const PORT = 8000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  fileServer.serve(req, res);

}).listen(PORT);
```

[In browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyCKd.png)

[In terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed0ox.png)

Comment: Well, the mentioned package is related to CPU information. Of course, the information will not match. WebAssembly runs inside an sandbox, provided by the browser (or other runtime) and doesn't have full access of the machine. It doesn't have the same instructions. For instance, you can't use AVX2 on WASM. Information about cache size is also unknown from WASM.

Comment: Hmm, it seems right if it is running in sandbox, then the output would be different. Is there a way I can get full CPU info from browser.

Comment: The only way I know to that would be by using ActiveX components in very outdated versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because your question is not self-contained. One must click links to understand your question. On Stack Overflow put everything in the question. Links are fine for references, but not for the primary content. Images can be copy and pasted into the question body not requiring links. Links change, are deleted, etc rendering your question useless in the future. Edit your question to follow Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: I thought it was downvoted because it was an question that could be avoided by reading the specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in the end both is run on the same the CPU that is not true technically. WASM is bytecode for an Virtual CPU. That bytecode is translated into machine bytecode by most browsers and then executed. But it secured that from this virtual machine nearly no access can be made to the real machine except he accepted API. So whatever functions they will most likely fall or where replaced by dummy functions and so on return error codes or dummy values that where chosen in a way they can be distinguished from real values.

Comment: Any resources I can read more about it? I searched on google but couldn't find any useful

Comment: Everything external an WASM module is allowed to call must be imported. And then will be supplied to the WebAssembly.Instance. My guess is it was not supplied there. And that is most because it isn't even possible on most browsers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817775/can-i-detect-cpu-type-and-speed-and-or-amount-of-ram-a-computer-has-from-a-web